# Additional "GO" after liquibase update

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

After update to liquibase 3.6.1 our old `<sql>` changeSets broke if they used DECLARE variables.

Apparently additional GO statements are now added where there are empty rows, this is not how it used to work and it now makes our old files throw
`liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Must declare the scalar variable "@foo"`.

How would we either get around this or fix our older files to work on old database copies without being run again on up to date ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of T-SQL Variables is at the T-SQL batch.  Batch is completed with the "GO" command.
Therefore, after GO, @foo would have to be re-declared.

For example:

DECLARE @foo int = 0;

GO

SELECT @foo;  --  This line will give an error.

If the GO is moved to the end, then it will work, and return the value of @foo.

DECLARE @foo int = 1;

SELECT @foo;  --  This line will return 1.

GO

Batch Scope is not a new behavior of SQL Server, it's been the behavior since version 1.

Try looking at LiquidBase's 'sqlFile' tag, and see if the endDelimiter attribute or splitStatements attribute have been set incorrectly.

Comment: I know that, the issue is that additional GO have been added at empty lines to the liquibase scripts that ran fine before the version upgrade.

Comment: Can you check the 'sqlFile' tag?  https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html

Comment: Oh I completely missed the part with splitStatements, it seems like they had a bug they fixed in some version that made our semicolons not count as statement splitters. With splitStatements="false" our script now work like they previously did, thank you!